# how we find out string with in special characters i.e T213-ASDF|silicon Valley|white using vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Range("A" & i), InStr(1, Range("A" & i), "|") + 1, InStr(1, Range("A" & i), "|") - 1 - InStr(1, Range("A" & i), "|"))

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Why there is Next i without For? What's your expected output?

Comment: Put your data then explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and pay attention to the added comments and tweak it accordingly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim str() As String

'Assuming data is in Column A, finding the last row with the data in column A
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Assuming data starts from Row2 in Column A
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lr)

For Each cell In rng
    str = Split(cell.Value, "|")
    'if the string in A2 is T123-ASDF|Silicon Valley|White
    MsgBox str(0)   'will return T123-ASDF
    MsgBox str(1)   'will return Silicon Valley
    MsgBox str(2)   'will return White

    'So if you want to return Silicon Valley in C2, try this
    cell.Offset(0, 2) = str(1)
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much,Its very helpful.

Comment: @Amjad.Ali You're welcome! Glad you found it helpful. Please take a minute to accept the answer as Solution to mark your question as Solved. :)